Rotating the vertex to the exact height

Vertex A is the center of rotation.
The projection is Right Orthographic (X Viewpoint).

How do I rotate vertex B (along with vertices C and D), to the same height (Z) as point A?
Vertex A value for Z (Global) = 1 mm.
The distances between A and B, B and C, C and D, must remain the same.


You can do this all without extruding vertices, parenting or anything:

Select vertex A, then Shift+S > Cursor to Selected. Also make sure that the Transform Pivot Point is set to 3D Cursor.


Set the Snapping options for Snap Base to either Active or Closest, the Snap Target to Vertex and make sure under Affect you have Rotate enabled (it does not matter if Move is enabled as well, you do not have to disable it).


Next you select the vertices B, C and D. If you have set the Snapping to Active, it is important to make B the active vertex (it should be white instead of orange). If you set it to Closest, it does not matter which vertex is active.


Now start rotating by pressing R. If you have chosen the option Active (and B is active element), it does not matter where your mouse is when you initiate the rotation. If you have chosen Closest, the mouse should be close to vertex B at the start. While rotating, hold down Ctrl and move your mouse towards vertex A until it indicates that it is snapping to the vertex. Then you can left-click to confirm the rotation.




Yes, this is what I noticed when going through Daniel's answer, no need to extrude and create a 2nd vertex if the 1st one works as well :) And as I pointed out in his answer, this solution doesn't work unfortunately for an arbitrary height, different than the pivot. There's also a more general problem: how to rotate a vertex to snap to any edge, not necessarily horizontal. I think there are addons for this but nothing in the vanilla Blender to my understanding.

@MarkusvonBroady You are right, this does not work with arbitrary heights and any edge. But since the answer was explicitly asking for the same height on Z as a specific other vertex, this is the simplest way to do it. And I see many questions here where people construct while aligning to global axes, so this still can be very helpful. And this method not only works horizontal, but vertical too or in X and Y direction if rotating on the Z axis. It all depends on how the mesh is oriented etc. and what someone needs.

Ahh...Yes! Rotating while moving cursor to pivot point (3d cursor). This is absolutely what I need.
Just to note that when you want to also rotate the following vertex (C, D) to Z height, you need to change Snap to: Edge. This will make it much easier for me to unwrap simple cylindrical models.
Thank you very much everyone!

@skulptron I'm not sure if I understand what you mean - so you do not want to keep the angles on the rest of the line, you want to straigthen the whole thing while maintaining the distances between vertices? And you mean rotating C and D after rotating B, C and D? Then there is no need to change to Edge. The important thing is you have to change the position of the 3D cursor to vertex B now, otherwise the distances between the vertices will change.

Yes, you're right... I don't know why the first attempts didn't work until I changed to Snap to Edge... Yes, my intention was to straigthen the whole thing while maintaining the distances between vertices - rotating C and D after rotating B, C and D...
I thought it was implied that the position of the 3D cursor to vertex B ( and so on) had to be changed.

@skulptron It might have been implied, I was just wondering if you did something else when you said you had to change to Edge snapping. The question never really stated it was about straightening the line - rotating B along with C and D around A sounded to me as if C and D should remain their relative angles.

@Gordon Brinkmann I didn't want to complicate with requests, your solution allows me to use it for my needs. I really appreciate your help and I hope it will benefit others.

Easy.

Make an horizontal edge from the center of rotation (extrude: e, y)
Select the center point, shift+s cursor to selected
Set the pivot point of rotation to 3d cursor (image)
Set the snap options to vertex
Select the points and Rotate, X (axis), B (to snap), click the the vertex you want to snap, click the line you want to snap to



Why do you all extrude a vertex?

I think you want to move to (not click) the vertex (not line) you want to snap to? https://i.imgur.com/GeIQekU.gif also you need to enable "rotation" in snapping options, also this answer too doesn't work in a general case when the desired height doesn't match rotation pivot point: https://i.imgur.com/8Ojt7Oa.gif

@MarkusvonBroady I agree mostly. The problem showing in your GIF is the following: if you move the vertices, the distances and angles relative to each other do not stay the same. That's why the question is explicitly about rotating around vertex A as pivot point, not moving. Of course if the desired height is different from the pivot point it gets more complicated. But as I see it, this question asks specifically for the same height for use cases where you want a certain edge, here A-B, as base aligned with a global axis while retaining the angles and edge lengths relative to each other.

We all extrude a vertex because it's a baseline for ANY rotation you want. If you don't want a horizontal line, extrude the vertex to any angle you want. You can rotate the extruded vertex with numeric values for having exact angles

This answer is universal, works for any angle, any base line. Doesn't count on tricks or needs the geometry to be at a specific position.


Select your A vertex and extrude an edge from it along the same axis (E Y) in the direction of your other vertex.

Select Snap on the top menu. In the same menu select Edge and only Rotate (at the bottom).

(You have already put your 3D cursor on A and select 3D Cursor on the top as center of rotation.) Select the following B, C, D vertex and you can do you rotation by pointing to your edge to snap your B vertex at the right height...


Maybe it exists a better solution... it's mine!

Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.
